# Docker compose how to mount containers to new volume that already exists

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm trying to mount my app and mongo to new volume as there's no space left on existing volume but still I'm getting that same error. There's something I'm not doing correct. I'm new to docker, please guide

Error:

```
ERROR: write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob735048270: no space left on device
```

Following is my docker compose file

```
version: "2"

    services:
      pim:
        build: .
        volumes:
           - pim-volume:.
        ports:
          - "5100:5100"
        links:
          - mongo
      mongo:
        container_name: mongo
        image: mongo
        volumes:
          - pim-volume:./data/db
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
        pim-volume:
            external: true
```

Following is volume inspect

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-12-22T09:08:50+04:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/pim-volume/_data",
        "Name": "pim-volume",
        "Options": {
            "device": "overlay",
            "o": "size=5GB",
            "type": "overlay"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to start clearing your space by removing orphaned volumes and images:

First, check your orphaned volumes:

```
docker volume ls -qf dangling=true
```

You can remove them by running:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

To remove old/unused images run:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f "dangling=true")
```